# code continue to run before onDataChange finished

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

my oncreate on fragment tab :

```
 @Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1_frag, container, false);
    Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
    if (bundle != null) {
        class_name = bundle.getString("tab1");
    }
    recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview_tab1);
    recyclerViewAdepter = new RecyclerViewAdepter(getContext(), list);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdepter);

    class_name = "oops";
    Log.d("tag6", class_name);
    return view;


}

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mapFromDB = new HashMap<String, String>();
    Log.d("tag1", class_name);
    db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("CLASS").child("123").child("day1");
    db.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Log.d("tag2", "ok");
            for (DataSnapshot dbclass : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                mapFromDB.put(dbclass.getKey().toString(), dbclass.getValue().toString());
                Log.d("tag3", "ok");
            }
            recyclerViewAdepter.set_map(mapFromDB);
            check = "123";
            Log.d("tag4", check);
            adding();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            check = "456";
            adding();

        }
    });


}

public void sendToDB()

{
    db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("CLASS").child(class_name).child("day1");
    db.setValue(recyclerViewAdepter.get_map());

}


void adding() {
    Log.d("tag5", check);
    list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(new days_fragment(ourdata.Hours[0], check));
    list.add(new days_fragment(ourdata.Hours[1]));
    list.add(new days_fragment(ourdata.Hours[2]));
    list.add(new days_fragment(ourdata.Hours[3]));
    list.add(new days_fragment(ourdata.Hours[4]));
    list.add(new days_fragment(ourdata.Hours[5]));
    list.add(new days_fragment(ourdata.Hours[6]));
    list.add(new days_fragment(ourdata.Hours[7]));
    list.add(new days_fragment(ourdata.Hours[8]));
    list.add(new days_fragment(ourdata.Hours[9]));
    list.add(new days_fragment(ourdata.Hours[10]));
    list.add(new days_fragment(ourdata.Hours[11]));
    list.add(new days_fragment(ourdata.Hours[12]));

}
```

and the logcat result are :

> com.example.project D/tag1: tt
>
> com.example.project D/tag5: 000

com.example.project D/tag6: oops

> com.example.project D/tag2: ok
>
> com.example.project D/tag3: ok
>
> com.example.project D/tag4: 123

tag 5&6 comes before 2,3,4 
why this is happing and how to resolve it ?

Comment: Firebase is asynchronous.

Comment: I recommend you see the last part of my anwser from this **[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47847694/how-to-return-datasnapshot-value-as-a-result-of-a-method/47853774)** and also take a look at this **[video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OvDZVV5CbQg)**.

Comment: i understand that. but how i make that part do it before others? 
the variable "check" changes on 

db.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener()

and if other code run before that, check wont be right

Answer (score 0):

Firebase event listeners work asynchronous. Retrieving data on **onCreateView** method must solve your issue. This will make your code more unreadable and complicated to understand but until now this is the solution I could apply and get a result. Please let me know if you find a better solution.